# Why symfony FOSRest bundle doesn't find the right controller?

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have two actions:

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("/items/{itemId}")
 */
public function getAction(UuidInterface $id): View
```

And

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("/items/available")
 */
public function getAvailableAction() : View
```

The thing is that when I'm trying to call getAvailableAction by a link `items/available`, the getAction is being called. I guess it interprets the word available as an `{itemId}` somewhy.

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You guessed right. Just define a proper requirement:

```
 /**
  * @Rest\Get("/items/{itemId}", requirements={"itemId" = "\d+"})
  */
```

If your `itemId` is an [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), change the number regex from `\d+` to `[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}` or a simplified `[a-fA-F0-9\-]{36}`.

Don't forget to clear the cache.

Comment: Hm, is there any configuration setting that I could use instead of writing regex everytime?

Comment: Custom annotation class and define the requirement in there, eg. `class RestGetUuid extends Get {…`. Or stop using annotations and embrace YAML configuration where you can control route order.

Comment: Are both methods part of the same class? In that case you could just change the order in which they are defined so that the route for `getAvailableAction()` is matched first.